# VS2013 express Intellisense is very slow... Unreal engine 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, unreal-engine4

Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense is SOOOOO DAYMMMMM SLOWWW... I have like an insane rig and it takes about 30 seconds to a minute to pop up the intellisense menus... Sometimes, it doesn't even show!... and i have to reopen the file to get it to actually come up? It's making learning Unreal engine really blooming difficult.

Is there any obvious reasons why this is so slow.

- I've deleted my sdf file, but that did jack diddly squat.
- I've run in safe mode

It doesn't seem to be context specific, it's just slow throughout the application.

Comment: I think you're getting down votes because you haven't shown an effort in finding a solution besides deleting the .sdf file. That usually doesn't go over well. I found a couple of things I would try by just doing a simple Google search. Export VS settings, reset VS settings, import VS settings for example or starting Visual Studio in safe mode to rule out 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Reset VS settings, I wonder... I mean I've never changed any of them... Does your intellisense often go slow? or is it fast... I mean, I have nothing to compare to, but it seems pretty unusable most of the time.

Comment: This question is probably not recoverable. You need to: 1) Remove all subjective and idiomatic elements from the post, including but not limited to "insanely", "sooooo daymmmmm slowww", "like an insane rig", and "jack diddly squat". Replace them with specific timing details and clear description of the hardware/software in use. 2) Include specific information about your environment and project configuration (Visual Studio uses different IntelliSense providers for each language, and they all work differently).

Comment: Also, it doesn't belong on StackOverflow. That's why I made the initial close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the unreal engine source code from git rather than relying on the unreal engine executable file project creation... You get an unreal batch file that creates the visual studio project for you.

When you do it the above way, it binds intellisense stuff and it is lightning quick now. I assume it's because VS was having to dive into files that were dll rather than just part of the project solution... (unpacked)?

A word of warning, it takes ages (30 minutes for me) for the first build doing it this way...

If you are unsure of how to use the source code from git, follow this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usjlNHPn-jo&index=68&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gaCL2XjKluO7N2Pmmw9pvhE

It makes a HUGE difference!

Another thing that worked for me is to increase the C++ Max cached translation units to 15.

Comment: I installed everything using the executable and rather not go over the process of installing it again. There must be a way to speed intellisense up with a regular install.